Select class where parent is last child in
I have a simple html hierarchy:
<div>
    <div>
       <div class="custom-class">whatever</div>
   </div>
    <div>
       <div class="custom-class">whatever</div>
   </div>
   <div>
       <div class="custom-class">thing i want to select</div>
   </div>
</div>

I am currently adding attributes to .custom-class but would like to add a specific attribute to only the last-child's .custom-class.
However I would like to apply the style inside the .custom-class that is being used for all children. Its parent does not have a custom class, nor does the grandparent.
A pseudo example would be:
.custom-class {
    color: red;

    &.where-parent-is-last-child {
        color: green;
    }
}

Meaning, I would like to know the scss selector that can access <div class="custom-class">thing I want to select</div> without affecting the other siblings INSIDE the singular .custom-class class.

I'm not sure I understand, are you just asking how to do: :last-child > .custom-class? Or is there more to it?

This applies the green color to .custom-class only when it's the child of a <div> that is the :last-child in its container.
.custom-class {
  div:last-child > & {
      color: green;
  }
}

Result
Here is the compiled CSS with the accompanying HTML in a snippet:


div:last-child > .custom-class {
  color: green;
}
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="custom-class">Whatever</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="custom-class">Whatever</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="custom-class">Thing I want to select</div>
  </div>
</div>




:last-child > .custom-class should do what you are asking for: This selects custom-class if it is a direct child of an element that is a last-child.


:last-child > .custom-class {
  color: green;
}
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="custom-class">whatever</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="custom-class">whatever</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="custom-class">thing i want to select</div>
  </div>
</div>




It' supposed to be inside the .custom-class like done in sass fashion. I'll edit the question.

Doesn't sass allow certain extended selectors that are nested?

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector/
